# RethinkDb update table row based on existing value

Tags: scala, rethinkdb

I have a simple table in RethinkDb which I need to update existing row, this is a very simple table with just two columns `Id` and `value` whenever I have a new record with the same `Id` I want to add new value to the existing value for example if I have a row in table with values `{id: 25 , value:50}` and I have a new record `{id:25 , value:100}` the row should be updated to be `{id : 25, value 150}`.

in the Java documentation, I found this example which seems to fit my requirement https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/java/update/

```
r.table("posts").get(1).update(
    post -> r.hashMap("views", post.g("views").add(1).default_(0))
).run(conn);
```

however, I can't run this example in my code, because I'm getting this error 
`Missing parameter type: post`

[image]

I'm using scala with RethinkDb java drivers to connect to rethinkDb

Answer (score 0):

I'm evaluating rethinkdb,
tried this code:

```
package de.jvr

import com.rethinkdb.RethinkDB

object Test {

 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


  // database
  val r = RethinkDB.r
  val conn = r.connection().hostname("localhost").port(28015).connect()

  try {
   // existing database "test"

   // drop table
   r.db("test").tableDrop("posts").run(conn)

   // create table
   r.db("test").tableCreate("posts").run(conn)

   // insert
   r.table("posts").insert(
    r.hashMap("id", 25)
    .`with`("value", "50")
   ).run(conn);

   // update
   r.table("posts").get(25).update(r.hashMap("value", "100")).run(conn);

   //print
   val cursorJava: com.rethinkdb.net.Cursor[java.util.HashMap[String, String]] = r.table("posts").run(conn)
   cursorJava forEach(x => println(x))

   // or in the Data Explorer: r.table("posts")
  } catch {
   case e:Throwable => println("exception: " + e.toString)
  }


 sys.exit(0)
 }
}
```

/*

Cmd-line result: [info] {id=25, value=100}

Data Explorer:

1 row returned. Displaying rows 1-1
{

"id": 25 ,
 "value": "100"

}

have this options in build.sbt:

fork in run := true

trapExit := false

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xexperimental")
*/